# Duplicate record from file input

Tags: c++, arrays, file, eof, records

i got a problem over there. When i use the function below, i got a duplicate of the last entry in my agenda (array of records, "contact"s). How can i resolve this problem? Sorry if i asked a Q previously answered

```
void load(agenda a,int& r){
    r=0;
    contact c;
    fstream f;

    f.open("agenda.txt",ios::in);
    if(!f)
        cout<<"\nError!";
    else
        while(!f.eof()){
            f>>c.name;
            f>>c.number;
            strcpy(a[r].name,c.name);
            strcpy(a[r].number,c.number);
            r++;
        }
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Possible problems: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Oh well, thank you and sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file need to reach `EOF` for `eof()` return true.

If there is a white space after the last value you won't reach the `EOF` till the next read try.

you can check if each read has succeeded like this:

```
if(!f>>value) break;
```

or iterate till `>>` operator will failed like this:

```
while(f>>c.name>>c.number){
   ...
}
```